# How to update all items in a dictionary ? iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a uipickerview, which has a dictionary as a datasource.
I want to be able to update every single row of this picker view, and add a number at the end, I started by trying to update every row, but it doesn't seem like its working.

I add an item to the dictionary like this:

```
[[dataBundleDictFinal objectForKey:@"BundleDisplayNames"] addObject:@"New row!"];
```

"New row!" is the text that appears in the pickerview

Then I'm trying to update every row, to say "hello", I try something like this:

```
for(NSInteger i; i < numofrows; i++) {
    [[dataBundleDictFinal objectForKey:@"BundleDisplayNames"] setObject:@"hello" atIndex:(NSUInteger)i];
}
```

but this does not change the pickerview even though I reload it afterwards. Am I doing something wrong while updating the dictionary, or is it some kind of other problem with the pickerview ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the loop initialization is missing:

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i < numofrows; i++)
```

Comment: oh thanks! that fixed it! :)
weird that it didn't do any errors

Comment: uninitialized, it very well could have exceeded numofrows, so the loop was complete.